# How to take professional SEM images of bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology, microscopy

I am new to using SEM microscope I would like to take clear pictures of Bacillus subtilis. My sample is dropped on a piece of paper and carbon-coated. The picture is showing crumbs of something (maybe dust or burned bacteria). One of my images:

[image]

What is the problem here am I too using too much energy from the gun? or is it distance and magnification?

Comment: I'm no expert at all, but I don't think paper is normally part of the SEM sample prep...

Comment: Where did you find the protocol used for sample preparation? It's hard to troubleshoot without more details. SEM protocols for bacteria often include a fixative step to preserve structures and a dehydration step prior to sputter coating (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3352184/). The one cell I can see in this image looks alright. Is it possible that you didn't apply enough sample, or didn't properly target the sample when collecting images?

Comment: The sample had a high optical density of bacteria. what do you mean by properly targeting the sample?

Comment: Loooooong ago, when I did some SEM, prep of a sample included fixating the specimen, removing the water by flushing the sample with acetone or ethanol, then liquid CO2, then letting the CO2 evaporate off, then putting the specimen on a stand in a vacuum chamber and bombarding it with electrons. I don't remember gold, but that was 40? years ago. It's not a simple process, and I'm surprised someone let you use their SEM without training you in its use.

Comment: Did you wash the cells before following the fixation procedure. I faced the same issues. Washing 3 to 4 times with PBS before and after fixation solved my problem and gave me crisp images of bacillus subtilis.
Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was introduced to SEM microscopy last year at school so I'm not the most reputable source. But here's what I think could be the reasons:

- May need to coat in a more conductive heavy metal (like Gold) if you can access it
- Smaller Aperture + Larger Distance (to increase the field of view)
- Mount the sample on an aluminium stub with conductive sticky pads rather than paper
- Adjust contrast

Comment: I have Mount the paper which is holding sample on an aluminium stub with conductive sticky pads. How about the gun power?